# Cassandra on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, cassandra

I am new to GCP and I want to deploy Cassandra nodes on Google Cloud. What are the advantages of using Cassandra containers over directly deploying Cassandra on these nodes?

Comment: I know nothing of Cassandra ... but searching around I seem to get the impression that there is "generic" story on merits of Cassandra running on native OS as opposed to Cassandra running in a container ... see for example ... https://insidebigdata.com/2017/06/21/want-run-cassandra-container-need-solve-4-problems-first/

Answer (score 1):

We tried this scenarios:

- Running cassandra in kubernetes
- Running cassandra in docker on VM instances
- Running cassandra on VMs without docker

**Short version:**

We decided to run on VMs (docker)

**Long version**

Building a working kubernetes setup takes some time. You need to find out, how to set ip adresses right, how to pick right disk types. And how to access machines.
When it comes to installing sidecars like cassandra reaper we found the configuration being easier when you are on a dedicated vm.

Same story with disaster recovery. We backup attached disks daily and keep them for a certain period. There were cases where we need to reattach a disk from a backup additionally to a running version. That was again easier than in a kubernetes environment. Remember - when we are talking about disaster recovery most likely you are under stress because things just got f... up ;)

In the end both solutions work but a dedicated VM per node is easier to manage.

**So:**

Docker: yes (or better docker-compose), because you dont have to worry about VM setup.
Kubernetes: rather no (but this is a question of personal taste)